# Shuffle Function Doesn't Shuffle Array Elements (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays

I'm learning PHP by working through a book. I realised that PHP's inbuilt `shuffle()` function destroys key-value associations upon shuffling. So I decided to write my own shuffling function that would keep the original array keys but would map them to different values (how hard can it be I thought)? An hour later, I'm still unable to get the function to work, so I decided I'm better served throwing in the towel on this and seeking help. I would outline the (final version of the) the function, and then explain what I've tried so far.

---

### My Code

```
<?
    function swap(&$a, &$b)
    {
        $tmp = $a;
        $a = $b;
        $b = $tmp;
    }

    function shuffleX($arr) #Shuffles the key-value associations in an array.
    {
        $keys = array_keys($arr);   #extract the keys from the array.
        $length = count($keys);
        $i = 0; #Index.
        while ($i < $length-1) 
        {
            $target = rand(($i+1), $length-1);  #This ensures that no value ends up mapped to the same key.
            swap($arr[$keys[$i]], $arr[$keys[$target]]);    #Swap each element of the array with another.
            $i++;
        }
    }
?>
```

The array I used for testing purposes was: `$statesX = ["CA" => "California", "NY" => "New York", "FL" => "Florida", "WA"=> "Washington"];`
I tested this function in the PHP interactive shell (`shuffleX()` is renamed because I can't redefine already defined functions, so I copy-paste and change the name whenever I edit something):
[image]

---

### My Attempts at Solving the Problem (Not Necessarily in Chronological Order)

- I confirmed that swap is working and that it indeed swaps key-value associations for associative arrays:
  [image]
- I confirmed that `array_keys()` returns the keys of the array:
  [image]
- I confirmed that I can access the array elements using `array_keys()`:
  [image]
- I confirmed that `rand()` works in producing random values even for arrays of small sizes:
  [image]

At this point I decided that I'd spent too much time perusing my code, and that I should ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `shuffleX` function accepts the array by value.  In order for the caller to see its modifications, it needs to accept the array by reference: `function shuffleX(&$arr)`.